# Correct application of Tannery's Theorem to Show Riemann Zeta $\zeta(s) \rightarrow 1$ as $\sigma \rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, riemann-zeta

The Riemann zeta function is described by the series $\zeta(s)=\sum 1/n^s$ for $\sigma>1$ where $s=\sigma+it$.

To show that the $\zeta(s)\rightarrow1$ as $\sigma\rightarrow\infty$ we might be tempted to use

$$\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{1^{s}}+\frac{1}{2^{s}}+\frac{1}{3^{s}}+\frac{1}{4^{s}}+\ldots$$

and say that as $\sigma\rightarrow\infty$, the magnitude of each term $|n^{-s}|=n^{-\sigma}$ tends to zero as $\sigma\rightarrow\infty$ for all n except $n=1$.

**However** - this assumes $\lim_{\sigma\rightarrow\infty}\sum 1/n^s = \sum \lim_{\sigma\rightarrow\infty} 1n^s$ which we haven't shown is true.

To do this we can use **Tannery's Theorem** ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tannery%27s_theorem), [other](https://ckrao.wordpress.com/2011/07/24/tannerys-theorem/)).

**Question:** This question is about checking I have applied Tannery's theorem correctly.

---

**Step 1**

We start by stating Tannery's theorem to make sure we understand it. We start by defining:

$$S_j = \sum_{k}^{\infty} f_k(j) \;  \text{ converges for all } j$$
$$ \lim_{j \rightarrow \infty} f_k(j) = f_k \; \text{ exists} $$

If the following bounds apply,

$$| f_k(j) | \leq M_k$$
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} M_k < \infty $$

Then we can say,

$$ \lim_{j \rightarrow \infty} S_j= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f_k $$

---

**Step 2**

We cast our challenge, and take care with the changed variable names.

We are interested in

$$ \lim_{\sigma\rightarrow\infty} \sum_n 1/n^s = \lim_{\sigma\rightarrow\infty} \sum_n f_n(\sigma) $$

where $f_n(\sigma) = 1/n^s = 1/n^{\sigma+it}$.

We then establish the preliminary conditions:

$$\sum_{n}^{\infty} f_n(\sigma) \;  \text{ converges for all } \sigma>1$$

We are only interested in $\sigma>1$.

$$ \lim_{\sigma \rightarrow \infty} f_n(\sigma) = f_n \; \text{ exists} $$

Here:

$$ f_n = \begin{cases} 0 \text{ for } n>1\\ \\1 \text{ for } n=0 \end{cases} $$

---

**Step 3**

We then check the bounds:

$$| f_n(\sigma) | \leq M_n = 1/n^\sigma \text {converges for } \sigma > 1$$

$$ \sum M_n < \infty \text { for } \sigma >1$$

---

**Step 4**

Which finally allows us to say

$$ \lim_{\sigma \rightarrow \infty} \sum_n 1/n^s = \sum_{n} f_n = \sum 1+0+0+0 \ldots = 1 $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is close.  There's really just one issue you need to fix: $M_n$ cannot depend on $\sigma$.

A simple way to fix this is to assume $\sigma \geq 2$ and then define $M_n = 1/n^2$.

Comment: Hi Biran, thanks for your helpful input here. Can I define $M_n=1/n^\alpha$ where $1<\alpha \leq \sigma$ so $M_n$ is independent of $\sigma$ and our domain is still $\sigma>1$ ? Here $\sum 1/n^\alpha$ converges.

Comment: @Tariq I'm not sure what property you're trying to preserve by looking at the entirety of $\sigma > 1$ when we're taking the limit as $\sigma \to \infty$.  The smallest series that majorizes $\sum 1/n^\sigma$ for all $\sigma > 1$ is $\sum 1/n$, which is divergent.  The reason we can apply Tannery's theorem here is that we don't care what happens for $\sigma \approx 1$, and we only need to majorize the subset of series $\sum 1/n^\sigma$ for a fixed $\alpha > 1$ and all $\sigma \geq \alpha$.

Comment: Thanks @Brian - I was asking to make sure I understood the mathematics and the theorem. If the answer was "no, you can't do that", it would tell me that I had misunderstood something. Thanks for your patience with my learning style.