# Exchanging limit and sum operators for finite sums.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I keep reading that the limit and sum operators can be exchanged, as follows, when the sum is finite $\sum_{1}^{N}$.

$$\lim_{\sigma \rightarrow \infty}\sum \frac{1}{n^s}= \sum \lim_{\sigma \rightarrow \infty } \frac{1}{n^s}$$

( In the case the sum is infinite, we can use Tannery's theorem to establish the validity. )

**Question: Why is it obvious the limit and sum operators can be exchanged for finite sums?**

Comment: You might want to check out this Wikipedia article’s [section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Properties) about properties of limits.

Comment: regarding the Tannery's theorem - I asked a question on its application which wasn't answered - I'd appreciate thoughts on it, perhaps I asked the question badly? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4252541/correct-application-of-tannerys-theorem-to-show-riemann-zeta-zetas-rightar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't "obvious", per se, but it follows from a very elementary property of limits, that $\lim a_n + \lim b_n = \lim (a_n + b_n)$, i.e. the sum of the limits is the limit of the sum. Repeated application of this property shows that you can exchange limits with finite sums.

Comment: As in gt's answer above,   this only holds if the two left hand side limits exist

Answer (score 5):

Only obvious if the individual limits exist, then it's like saying $\lim (f(x) + g(x)) = \lim f(x) + \lim g(x)$.

For a counterexample, consider $f(x) = x+5$ and $g(x) = 5-x$, then
$f(x) - g(x) = 10$ so as $x \to \infty$, we have $\lim (f(x)+g(x)) = 10$ and $\lim f(x)$ and $\lim g(x)$ do not exist.

Comment: very useful point - thank you

Answer (score 1):

Say you have two limits, ${\lim_{x\to a}f(x)}$ and ${\lim_{x\to a}g(x)}$, both of which converge. Then it's elementary to prove that ${\lim_{x\to a}(f(x) + g(x))=\lim_{x\to a}f(x) + \lim_{x\to a}g(x)}$.

Now, instead take ${N}$ functions, ${f_1(x),...,f_N(x)}$, all of which have convergent limits as ${x\to a}$ once again. Then we can simply use induction to show
$$
\lim_{x\to a}\sum_{n=1}^{N}f_n(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{N}\lim_{x\to a}f_n(x)
$$
Try it. Do the base case of ${N=1}$, then use the property ${\lim_{x\to a}(f(x) + g(x))=\lim_{x\to a}f(x) + \lim_{x\to a}g(x)}$ along with the induction hypothesis to prove this holds for any $N$ above.

If you get stuck, let me know in a comment and I will show you.